# Why is this illegal initialization syntax?

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization, rvalue

```
template<typename T>    
void func(T* arr, size_t length)
{
    size_t size_half = length / 2;
    T* left = arr, right = arr + size_half; // Cannot initialize a variable of type 'int' with an rvalue of type 'int *'
}
```

It seems to me like the compiler thinks right is of type int instead of int*, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the * is attached to the right, and not the left.

Look at it more like:

```
T  *left,  right
```

That's just how the language syntax is defined.
You can fix it by:

```
T *left=...,*right=....;
```

Comment: Well, this also gets into the whole where to place the pointer syntax argument :)
The way I used to think about it was int* as being its own type, just as double* and double are types, so i always placed the * on the left.
I've been swayed to start placing the pointer to the right now, for situations like this.

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera The real solution is to stick to one single declaration per line. Putting the pointer on the right also looks silly. Unfortunately, this crappy syntax is inherited from C.

Comment: A common solution that avoids ambiguity is to first do something like:  `typedef T*  pointer;`   and then do   `pointer left=...,right=...;`

Comment: @Photon: I don't recommend a `typedef T* pointer;` because it makes code less readable.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch - I don't know why you would consider it less readable.  Even the standard library implementations (both g++ and Visual Studio) use such definitions all over the place.

Comment: So it seems it's subjective.  I find it improves readability.   I'm of course referring to the `typedef`, not necessarily to the name `pointer`

Answer (score 2):

In types, the `*` apply to the following , so you should code:

```
template<typename T> void func(T* arr, size_t length) {
  size_t size_half = length / 2;
  T *left = arr, 
    *right = arr + size_half; 
  //etc...
}
```

Actually, I think that you should declare one pointer per line:

```
  T *left= arr;
  T *right= arr + size_half;
```

or even (C++11 style):

```
  T *left {arr};
  T *right {arr + size_half};
```

or

```
  auto left {arr};
  auto right {arr + size_half};
```

declaring each pointer on its line is IMHO much more readable.

BTW, you might consider using `std::array<T>` or `std::vector<T>`

Comment: Yeah, thanks, unfortunately the person who asked me to write this is backwards as heck and wants me to use c-style arrays :/

Comment: well, the whole point in my mind of the comma-delimited initialization was to do one-liners. Unless there is another purpose behind them, I would use them to do one liners, and your second example for 2 liners.

Comment: I believe that a one line pointer definition should be very short and readable, so I won't code like you want.

Answer (score 0):

It will be like this

```
T *left = arr, *right = arr + size_half;
```